# What's the right metaphor for a dependency injection library?

Tags: c++, oop, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I'm the author of a small C++ library that implements dependency injection (I think someone would call it "IoC container").

I've always thought that finding a good metaphor for a library can help in many ways:

- it simplifies the use of the library
- it helps the library's author to find the right abstractions
- it's a guide to check the soundness of the design
- it's a way to find meaningful names for the classes
- and so on...

Now, in my library, I used the device/plug metaphor: your classes are "devices", their dependencies are "plugs", and you can connect a plug in another device. This is a code example:

```
REGISTERED_CLASS( Foo ), public Device
{
...
private:
    Plug< Bar > bar;
...
};
...
catalog.Create( "myFoo", "Foo" );
catalog.Create( "myBar", "Bar" );
...
catalog[ "myFoo" ].Plug( "bar" ).Into( catalog[ "myBar" ] );     // this means myFoo.bar = myBar
```

Well, I'm not quite satisfied by this metaphor, because:

- in real world, you insert plugs into sockets, so the source class should have a plug and the destination class a socket, but in the "code world" I have a pointer of a class pointing to another class;
- my metaphor doesn't work very well when you have an association with cardinality > 1. I tried with a `MultiplePlug< T >` (it's basically a `std::list< Plug< T > >`), but it does not sounds good: what is a "multipleplug" in the real world?

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/wallaroo/) you can find my library.
Do you have any suggestion for a metaphor that fits better my code?

(Still, if you should have any other good suggestions about the library, they'll be welcome!)

Thank you very much.

**Note**: I know there is another question with subject "What's a good metaphor for Dependency Injection", but this is not a duplicate of it.

**Edit**: [This](http://www.carlopescio.com/2012/03/episode-2-controller-strikes-back.html) is a discussion on the subject in a comment of a famous blog post.

**Edit2**: Finally, I decided to change the syntax to this nicer and simpler syntax:

```
// explicit catalog
use( myCatalog["myBar"] ).as( "bar" ).of( myCatalog["myFoo"] );

// implicit catalog:
within( myCatalog )
{
    use( "myBar" ).as( "bar" ).of( "myFoo" );
    ...
}
```

Comment: In a pipeline-processing framework I worked on, we called your `Plug` a `Pin` and `MultiplePlug` a `Connector` (a connector has multiple pins).

Comment: @AndréCaron Actually at first I used component and pin as metaphor (the metaphor of software Integrated Circuit). But the problem is in the real world you wire a pin with another pin and not a pin with a component. I hope you can get my point. (I edited the question with a link to a blog discussion about the subject in which we talked about the component/pin metaphor)

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is for the configuration phase. If you insist on the the `Plug` and `Into` terminology:

```
// this means myFoo.bar = myBar
catalog[ "myFoo" ].Into( "bar" ).Plug( catalog[ "myBar" ] );
```

where `Plug` is used as a verb i.e. "to plug". If you creating a fluent interface try to formulate meaningful sentences. If I wanted to configure several dependencies of "myFoo" then I'd be quite happy to write:

```
catalog[ "myFoo" ].
    .Into( "bar").Plug( "myBar" ) 
    .Into( "some_other_member" ).Plug( "that_other_instance" );
```

What's a bit unusual is that, normally, when doing configuration you are dealing with types not with instances...

Comment: Actually, I think that in english `obj.plug(x).into(y)` is more fluent, and you can equally chain several dependenies. But I'm not a native english speaker, so I might be wrong. Anyway: I'd like a different metaphor. What do you mean by "doing configuration"? In my types I define the type of dependencies (e.g.: in class Foo I have a pointer to a class Bar named bar), then, at run time, I decide that a particular instance of class Foo points to a particular instance of class Bar (or a subclass).

Comment: Yes it is, but then shouldn't it be other way round: `catalog[ "myFoo" ].Plug( catalog[ "myBar" ] ).Into( "bar" );`? What I proposed was sort of "enumeration": you enumerate members of instance from catalog using `Into` and tell what is to be `plugged in`.

Comment: With regard to the other point: I configure my "catalog" to contain types. In your DSL I'd say: `catalog("Foo").Into("bar").Plug("Bar");`. Which means: for any instance of type "Foo" and its dependency "bar", plug an instance of concrete type "Bar". In such scenarios "Foo" is an instance of concrete type which has a plug (a dependency on an) interface `IBar`. This dependency is configured to be satisfied by an implementation of "Bar". This is how I use dependency containers which might be a different scenario from what you want to achieve...

Comment: Well, the idea was that you have a class with a plug (its attribute). Then you plug the plug into another class. You don't plug a class into a plug as your syntax is suggesting. Anyway, I'd like to come up with a whole different metaphor.

Comment: I think we are speaking about different mechanism. My catalog is a catalog of instances, not classes. In Wallaroo (my library) when you say `catalog["myFoo"].Plug("bar").Into(catalog["myBar"])` it means: the pointer `myFoo.bar` points to the instance `myBar`.

Comment: I understood that, but normally, dependency injection is about types. Of course you are not "plugging a class into a plug" by: `catalog("Foo").Into("bar").Plug("Bar")`. In typical DI scenario that would mean "use instance of type Bar to satisfy dependency of an (any) instance of "Foo", whenever it is created. Your library kind of explicitely configures the object graphs used in a program which is what Dependency Containers "calculate" on the fly...

Comment: I see. So maybe wallaroo is not a dependency injection library. Still, its behavior is what I need and want it to be.

Comment: Of course. This is a completely valid requirement and it is a part of a typical DC functionality. The traditional type based DI is inherently difficult to implement for native C++ - you need a lot of conventions and restrictions...

Comment: I'd look at wallaroo as an implementation of the [multiton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern)

Comment: Hm, I'd consider the "multiton pattern" somewhat artificial, but yes, seems to fit here. In the end, a DC implementation will allow you to configure this behavioral aspect, usually as some kind of creation policy...